# How could I different the subjunctive mood from wrong tense or singular from in third personal?

Tags: grammar, tenses, subjunctive-mood

Here is the example, which is right?

It's important he know this.
It's important he knows this. 
It's important he has known this.

or, those above all right, but express different meaning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The third form of the sentence could be grammatically correct but expresses an unlikely thought, implying he no longer knows this, but it is currently important that he knew it some time in the past. It seems to be motivating the listener to take some action to ensure that the person who currently may not know it, did know it in the past. This is impossible without time travel.

The final "s" in "knows" is third person not plural, mainly because plurality applies to nouns not verbs I suppose.

As for the subjunctive: I can't do better than point you at Wikipedia's [article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subjunctive_mood#The_subjunctive_in_English)

[Grammar Monster](http://www.grammar-monster.com/glossary/subjunctive_mood.htm) suggests "Through common usage, the non-subjunctive forms of verbs are gradually replacing the subjunctive forms."

Comment: thank you! I see. Is the first sentence subjunctive mood? so, the first sentence use the basic form in verb.

Comment: I think you are right.

Comment: Agreed. Here's another link to the present subjunctive: http://www.bbc.co.uk/worldservice/learningenglish/grammar/learnit/learnitv105.shtml

Comment: @Tragicomic: I have revised my answer. I feel uncomfortable with the first sentence although I believe it is a grammatically correct use of the subjunctive. This may reflect either that use of the subjunctive is in decline in my part of the Anglosphere or possibly that my use of English is not strictly correct.